# con.Open() get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. c#

Tags: c#

I Have connectionString `OracleConnection` when I try to do : `ConnectionString.Open();` I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
the code:

```
  private static OracleConnection _connectionString;
  private static OracleConnection ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connectionString == null)
            {
                _connectionString = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
            }

            return _connectionString;
        }
    }
ConnectionString.Open();
```

in the webConfig:

```
<add name="DB" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" connectionString="data source=test;Persist Security Info=true;user id=db;password=db"/>
```

Comment: Do you have another `ConnectionString` variable where you use `Open()`?

Comment: I dont know.. can I close all the connectionstring before?

Comment: It is bad practice to use a static property for a database connection. You should be using it as a local variable inside a `using` statement whenever you need it.

Comment: The property is `private`, it can be used only in this class, what is the problem to check? and closing the connection won't solve this problem, it will just shift the exception to another place.

Comment: can you share stack Trace with us?

Comment: Try this.
    <add name="DB" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" connectionString="Server=(local);data source=test;Persist Security Info=true;user id=db;password=db"/>